# grape-kaminari with grape-builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari, ruby-grape, jbuilder, grape-api

Is there a way to get this grape-kaminari to work alongside the grape-jbuilder gem?

I've tried just paginating the records in the actual API module endpoint:

```
resource :groups do
    desc "Return a list of groups belonging to your company."
    get "/", jbuilder: "v3/groups" do
      paginate(@groups)
    end
end
```

and I've also tried putting the paginate call inside of the jbuilder object:

```
json.array! paginate(@groups) do |group|
  json.partial! "v3/group", group: group, computer_array: false
end
```

Neither of which worked. Can someone help me make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out. You have to reset the variable to the paginated array like so:

```
resource :groups do
    desc "Return a list of groups belonging to your company."
    get "/", jbuilder: "v3/groups" do
      @groups = paginate(@groups)
    end
end
```